# Adding attribute to category and display category as per that attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, category, category-attribute

Magento by default provide adding attribute to the products but not to the category.Is there any way to add attribute to the category? I would like to have attribute with input type- multiple select .

My question is explained in 2 parts.

Detail eg:

Part 1:
I have a player(category) called XYZ and it should have attribute like team name.
When i say multiple select it means,player can be part of different teams.So i will select lets say 3 team names.

so

- player XYZ belongs to team A,B,C
- player ABC belongs to team A,B
- player PQR belongs to team B,C

Part 2:
Now i want to include this teams A,B,C in the menu(frontend) and

- when i select team A ->  it will display all players who have team A (attribute) selected
- Same for B,C.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your players should be products and your teams the categories.  Then you can assign the products/players to multiple categories/teams.

That said, to more directly answer your question, here's an [Inchoo Article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/) detailing how to add attributes to categories, hopefully you can use it as a starting point if you want/need to go that route.

Copying from the article in case it goes missing later:

SQL setup script:

```
    $installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'new_cat_attrb',  array(
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'New Category Attribute',
    'input'    => 'text',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => 0
));
$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'new_cat_attrb',
    '11'                    //last Magento's attribute position in General tab is 10
);
$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'new_cat_attrb');
$installer->run("
INSERT INTO `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity_int')}`
(`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `entity_id`, `value`)
    SELECT '{$entityTypeId}', '{$attributeId}', `entity_id`, '1'
        FROM `{$installer->getTable('catalog_category_entity')}`;
");
//this will set data of your custom attribute for root category
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(1)
    ->setImportedCatId(0)
    ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
    ->save();
//this will set data of your custom attribute for default category
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(2)
    ->setImportedCatId(0)
    ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
    ->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

And the config.xml:

```
<resources>
    <new_attribute_csv_setup>
      <setup>
        <module>New_Attribute</module>
        <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
      </setup>
      <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
      </connection>
    </new_attribute_setup>
    <new_attribute_setup_write>
      <connection>
        <use>core_write</use>
      </connection>
    </new_attribute_setup_write>
    <new_attribute_setup_read>
      <connection>
        <use>core_read</use>
      </connection>
    </new_attribute_setup_read>
</resources>
```

Comment: :i am explaining the exact scenario:
WE have football tshirt (final product to sell)
   This tshirt is associated with some players Called B.
   Now player B is a part of different club say club A,Club B,Club C.

Now in top menu i want to include different Club Names.
So when user select Club A , all players under club A will be displayed and when any particular player is selected ,all products associated with that players will be shown.

So now how what is preferable ?

Comment: Well how I would personally handle that is still make players "products" in the store.  Obviously you're not selling the players, so you'll need some kind of custom attribute like `for_sale` (default: yes) set to 'no' on players.  Update your .phtml files to only display the "Add to Cart"/Quantity sections if the product is for sale.  Then you could add your t-shirts/merchandise as Related Products and display the related products block wherever you wish.